# Parse Error and unrecognized media only css validation

Tags: html, css

Css wont validate and I keep getting these errors. I have an ending bracket, so I'm not sure what the problem is. There's a parse error on line 39. Unrecognized media only on lines 79 and 81. Then on lines 79 and 89 those have the parse error. If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

```
39.    nav a:{text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: bold;  }

nav a:link {color: #ffffff;}
nav a:visited {color: #808080;}
nav a:hover {color: #ff0000; } 

h1 {text-align: center; 
color: #ffffff; 
font-family: CustomHeaderFont}
h2 { text-align: center;
color: #ffffff; 
font-family: CustomHeaderFont}
h3 {text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: CustomHeaderFont}
p { font-family: CustomFont;
color: #ffffff; 
text-align: center;}

ul li { padding: 5px 0px; }


footer { font-size: 90%;    
text-align: center;
clear: right;
padding: 15px;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: CustomFont;
}

70.   @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
body { margin: 0; }
#wrapper { width: auto; }
main {margin-left: 0;}
nav {float: none; width: auto; }
nav li { display: inline-block; padding: 0.5em; }
nav ul { text-align: center; }
nav a { border-style: none; }
h1, h2,h3 { font-size: 120%; }
79.    p { font-size: 90%; } }

81.    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
h1, h2, h3{ font-size: 100%; }
p { font-size: 90%; }
main { margin: 0.5%;
   width: auto ;}
nav, nav ul, nav li { padding: 0;}
nav li { display: block; }
aside { display: none; }
89.    }

@font-face {
font-family: CustomFont;
src: url(Font/GlacialIndifference-Regular.otf); }

@font-face {
font-family: CustomHeaderFont;
src: url(Font/BLURRYFACE.ttf);
}

form { background-color: #000000;
        font-family: CustomFont;
        padding: 10px;
        }
fieldset{ width: 320px; 
          border: 2px ridge #ff0000;
          padding: 10px;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
          }
legend {  font-family: CustomHeaderFont;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
label { float: left;
        width: 100px;
        clear: left;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-family: CustomFont; 
    }
textarea, submit {margin-top: 10px;
                 display: block;
                 }
input checkbox {display: inline;
margin-bottom: 60px;}


table { border: 5px solid #ff0000;
        width: 600px;
        margin: auto;
        }
td, th {border: 1px solid #ff0000; 
        padding: 0.5em;
        font-family: CustomFont;}

caption { font-family: CustomHeaderFont;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 1.2em;
          padding-bottom: 0.5em;
          }
```

Comment: You'd benefit greatly from using consistent code-formatting. I would suggest always starting css properties on a new line and indent them, consistently.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

there is a `:` after `a` on line 39

Comment: Thank you for that!